# Showing confirmation box not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having issues making this javascript box come up, I think i am doing it wrong but cant figure out what it is. Please excuse have not worked with the Page.ClientScript much before. Basically, I want to display this box and if they click OK it will continue processing my logic otherwise if they click cancel it will keep them on the same page

This is what i have.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
"ConfirmBox", "Confirm('The numbers selected are not in the directory,
Do you wish to continue?');", true);
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is case-sensitive.
You mean `confirm`.